# Bootstrap - Sass: relative glyphicons icon path

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

How do I set a relative glyphicons icon path in bootstrap sass version?

By default, the path used in the css font-face is an absolute one.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?1422262129);
  src: url(/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?&1422262129#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?1422262129) format("woff2"), url(/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff?1422262129) format("woff"), url(/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf?1422262129) format("truetype"), url(/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg?1422262129#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format("svg");
}
```

But I need a relative one: "../fonts/bootstrap" - so in file _bootstrap-variables.scss, I set the $icon-font-path

```
$icon-font-path: "../fonts/bootstrap/"
```

which gives the following

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(/fonts/../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?1422262129);
  src: url(/fonts/../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?&1422262129#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/fonts/../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?1422262129) format("woff2"), url(/fonts/../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff?1422262129) format("woff"), url(/fonts/../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf?1422262129) format("truetype"), url(/fonts/../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg?1422262129#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format("svg");
}
```

In the web I found the tip to inlcude "bootstrap-sprockets" before the variables, the result is

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(font-path("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"));
  src: url(font-path("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix")) format("embedded-opentype"), url(font-path("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2")) format("woff2"), url(font-path("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff")) format("woff"), url(font-path("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf")) format("truetype"), url(font-path("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular")) format("svg");
}
```

The url itself seems ok - but where does this "font-path" come from, how do I get rid of it?

Or is there another way to specify a relative path? What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 9):

A simple way to fix this without using compass is to declare a font-path function before including bootstrap. Your sass should look like the following:

**app.scss**

```
// your bootstrap default overrides here

$icon-font-path: '../fonts/bootstrap/';

@function font-path($path) {
  @return $path;
}

@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';

// your application styles here
```

Bit of a hack, and i'm not sure if anything else won't work with a setup like this (not using compass) but it appears to be working for me so far.

Answer (score 2):

I used the **Compass without Rails** installation. Uncommenting the  `relative_assets` line in **config.rb** solved the issue for me.

```
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
relative_assets = true
```

Without changing `$icon-font-path` you should end up with something like this in your generated stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?1430235042);
  src: url(../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?&1430235042#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?1430235042) format("woff2"), url(../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff?1430235042) format("woff"), url(../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf?1430235042) format("truetype"), url(../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg?1430235042#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format("svg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the glyphicons icon font does only work when I include `bootstrap-compass`. I use Compass + Bootstrap in my projects with the following configuration:

**config.rb:**

```
require 'bootstrap-sass'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "./"
css_dir = "."
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
relative_assets = true
```

So, `relative_assets` enabled and `bootstrap-sass` as the only dependency.

Then, in my **style.scss**:

```
@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3";

@import "custom-bootstrap"; /* where I set stuff like $brand-primary etc */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap-compass"; /* this is what does the trick in glyphicons for me! */
@import "bootstrap";

.further {
  styles: here;
}
```

Hope it helps anyone!