# How to deal with fonts in bootstrap-sass and compass? How to include fonts on the page correctly?

Tags: css, fonts, compass, bootstrap-sass

In my Node.js app I use [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) and [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). Not [gulp-compass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compass) and tasks, but exactly Compass, I have Compass' `config.rb` file in app's root dir. I compile my assets with these commands:

```
$ compass watch
$ compass compile
```

And I don't understand how to include bootstrap's fonts on the page to enable glyphicons. Fonts are stored in `bower_components\bootstrap-sass\assets\fonts\bootstrap`. `Bootstrap-sass` variables for fonts are as follows:

```
$bootstrap-sass-asset-helper: false !default;

//== Iconography
//
//## Specify custom location and filename of the included Glyphicons icon font. Useful for those including Bootstrap via Bower.

//** Load fonts from this directory.

// [converter] If $bootstrap-sass-asset-helper if used, provide path relative to the assets load path.
// [converter] This is because some asset helpers, such as Sprockets, do not work with file-relative paths.
$icon-font-path: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, "bootstrap/", "../fonts/bootstrap/") !default;
// $icon-font-path: 'fonts/';

//** File name for all font files.
$icon-font-name:          "glyphicons-halflings-regular" !default;
//** Element ID within SVG icon file.
$icon-font-svg-id:        "glyphicons_halflingsregular" !default;
```

And Compass compiles it into this `css`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg");
}
```

And I don't have Glyphicons on the page because fonts are now found in `../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`.

How to deal with fonts? Do I have to manually move fonts from

```
bower_components\bootstrap-sass\assets\fonts\bootstrap
```

to my

```
public/css/fonts
```

this is where my compiled assets live and where a server fetches them from. And this is what I do now - I manually moved fronts to `public/css/fonts` and had to manually type different `@font-face`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
    src: url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg");
}
```

But is it the right way? Then why Compass is needed if I have to manually deal with fonts and paths?

There are several Compass options for fonts in `config.rb`. How to use them to make Compass care about fonts and paths? I tried these options but it seems they do not work, I didn't noticed any changes in `scss` => `css` compilation, whatever I set them. And documentation is quite miserable.

```
fonts_dir =
fonts_path =
http_fonts_path =
http_fonts_dir =
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may well find your answer here [Bootstrap - Sass: relative glyphicons icon path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148322/bootstrap-sass-relative-glyphicons-icon-path)

The TLDR version is that you should try uncommenting the relative_assets line from your config.rb